# Find the critical points of a multivariable function with constraints

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier, hessian-matrix

For my vector calculus class, I need to solve this problem:

> Let $$f(x,y)=x^3+8xy-8y^3-7x+14y$$
> Given that this function has critical points on the lines $3x=7$ and $3x=-3$, find and classify all critical points.

**MY SOLUTION**

Since we have some conditions on our critical points, I decided to use Lagrange multipliers method.

Thus, we have $\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g$ and, depending on which condition we choose, $g_{1}=3x-7=0$ or $g_{2}=3x+3=0$

I, then, need to find the partial derivatives of $f$, $g_{1}$, $g_{2}$: $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=3x^2+8y-7$$ $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=8x-24y^2+14$$ $$\frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial x}=3$$ $$\frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial y}=0$$ $$\frac{\partial g_{2}}{\partial x}=3$$ $$\frac{\partial g_{2}}{\partial y}=0$$

For our first condition ($g_{1}$), we have this system of equations: $$\begin{cases}3x^2+8y-7=3\lambda\\8x-24y^2+14=0\\3x-7=0\end{cases}$$

$\Rightarrow x=\frac{7}{3}$

$\Rightarrow y=\pm \sqrt{\frac{8x+14}{24}}$
$\Rightarrow y=\pm \sqrt{\frac{8\cdot \frac{7}{3}+14}{24}}=\pm \frac{7}{6}$

Using the first condition gave me 2 critical points: $(\frac{7}{3},\frac{7}{6})$ and $(\frac{7}{3},-\frac{7}{6})$

So, now, let's use our second condition ($g_{2}$) to find some other solutions:

$$\begin{cases}3x^2+8y-7=3\lambda\\8x-24y^2+14=0\\3x+3=0\end{cases}$$

$\Rightarrow x=-1$

$\Rightarrow y=\pm \sqrt{\frac{8x+14}{24}}$
$\Rightarrow y=\pm \sqrt{\frac{8\cdot -1+14}{24}}=\pm \frac{1}{2}$

Using the second condition gave me 2 other critical points: $(-1,\frac{1}{2})$ and $(-1,-\frac{1}{2})$

So now that I know what are the critical points, I want to classify them (local maximum, local minimum, saddle point). And, from what I remember from Calculus III, the rules to know the category of each point were:

> If $D>0$ and $f_{xx}>0$, then it's a minimum
>
> If $D>0$ and $f_{xx}<0$, then it's a maximum
>
> If $D<0$, then it's a saddle point
>
> If $D=0$, then we cannot determine
>
> where $D=f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}^2$

But, in this course, we have to compute the Hessian matrix and do something with the determinant and eigenvalues. I can see that the determinant of the Hessian matrix is the "D" I was using in Calc III but what about a $3\times 3$ matrix. If someone could explain it to me, it would be great.

Anyway, I calculated the Hessian and its determinant D: $$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}&\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\\\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}&\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 6x&8\\8&-48y\end{bmatrix}$$ $$D=f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}^2=6x\cdot -48y-8^2=-288xy-64$$

I, then, calculated D for each of my points and I concluded this, using what I learned in Calc III: $$D_{(\frac{7}{3},\frac{7}{6})}=-288\cdot \frac{7}{3}\cdot \frac{7}{6}-64=-848\Rightarrow (\frac{7}{3},\frac{7}{6})\mbox{ is a saddle point}$$ $$D_{(\frac{7}{3},-\frac{7}{6})}=-288\cdot \frac{7}{3}\cdot -\frac{7}{6}-64=720\Rightarrow (\frac{7}{3},-\frac{7}{6})\mbox{ is a local minimum}$$ $$D_{(-1,\frac{1}{2})}=-288\cdot -1\cdot \frac{1}{2}-64=80\Rightarrow (-1,\frac{1}{2})\mbox{ is a local maximum}$$ $$D_{(-1,-\frac{1}{2})}=-288\cdot -1\cdot -\frac{1}{2}-64=-208\Rightarrow (-1,-\frac{1}{2})\mbox{ is a saddle point}$$
But when I entered my answers into Webwork to have them validated, it told me that my maximum and minimum were correct but my two saddle points were wrong. So I asked my teacher to check for errors in Webwork and he said this: "Not all answers are correct, please check the condition $f_{x}=0$" but I didn't understand what that meant.

Can you tell me where my mistake is and how my teacher's hint could help me?

Thanks in advance for your help.

IsaacM

*My answer to @Andrei:*

*Do we really have to use $f_{x}=0$ ? Because I feel like it's not always true when we work with a constraint. For example, we want to optimize $f(x,y)=xy+1$ and $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$. We can see on the graph of the function that, when $g(x,y)$ is max $f_{x}$ is not zero. How is it the case ?*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the teacher asked you to do is to check if you really have a critical point. You get $x$ from the "constraint", $y$ from the condition that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$, but you did not check that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$. Let's look at the $(7/3,7/6)$ point. $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=3x^2+8y-7=3\frac{49}{9}+8\frac76-7=\frac{49+28-21}3\ne 0$$
You need to check for all your points.

Comment: I answered you in my original post because I needed to post a picture

Comment: Notice that I used quotes for constraint. The problem does not require you to be on that line. It just says that there are some critical points on that line. If you would have a real constraint, then the second derivatives in the Hessian that depend on $x$ should be ignored. You can't have saddle points if you are constrained onto a line.

Comment: Ok, so from what you're telling me I understand that we don't need the constraint since it's just telling us where are the critical points. But when I try to solve $f_{x}=0$ and $f_{y}=0$, I'm left with a non-linear system of equations. How would you do it ?

Comment: That's why they helped you by saying that $x=7/3$. You might have other solutions as well. But they are only interested in the solutions that are along the given lines. Remember that if at a given point not all derivatives are zero then it's **not** a critical point. You might have a maximum or a minimum in the $y$ direction, but in the $x$ direction is neither a local maximum or minimum.